# Failed to compile (react javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, charts, numeral.js

this is my problem i hope there is a solution

```
./src/LineGraph.js
Syntax error: D:/programming/corona-tracker-app/covid-19-tracker/src/LineGraph.js: Unexpected token (88:12)

  86 |   return (
  87 |     <div>
> 88 |       {data?.length > 0 && (
     |             ^
  89 |         <Line
  90 |         options={options}
  91 |           data={{
```

[code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrVTg.png)
[code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV7TW.png)

Comment: Add original code

Comment: You may need to update your compiler. Optional chaining you are using here on the error line is fairly new to ECMAScript. What library(ies) are you using for compiling your source files?

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://ismail9k.medium.com/use-javascript-optional-chaining-today-f0b1d080b3c6).

Comment: can you please tell the version of `react-scripts` from your `package.json`

Comment: "version": "0.1.0",

Comment: I am asking about the `react-scripts`. It should be inside `devDependencies`

Comment: "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you images of code, you handle null-safety (or having values) with a Typescript operator : `?.`

And when you define `data` object using `useState` in line 67, assigned an empty object.

The `LineGraph` component ran and it rendered with an empty object, If you want to check if `data` has values, this may helps you:

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

So:

```
return(
<div>
    {Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && (
        <Line 
        // options
        />
    )}
</div>
)
```